# How to improve the speed of a multiplier in verilog?

Tags: verilog

How to improve the speed of a multiplier in verilog?

Hi

I want to know about 'How to improve the speed of a multiplier without increasing clock speed in verilog?'

Does anyone know about regarding this?
We don't have much money to buy DesignWare of Synopsys's.
Unfortunately, Also we met some problem regarding speed limit of multiplier. So I trying to find way to improve multiplier without clock speed up. Especially, our ASIC has already approached to timing limit. We don't have timing margin.But We have to change regarding the multiplier logic.

For example, we have already met the all timing clock in synthesis.but we need to change the algorithm some multiplier regarding logic.

Comment: What have you tried? Why is the multiplier speed a problem? What clock speed are you using?

Comment: Thanks for asking me. Multiplier speed is important when we want speed up without increasing clock speed. So I have tried to find some method but it does not easy. We use almost 300~400Mhz clock speed.

Comment: I think your look that  the minimising the combinational logic side with flip-flop is just total system clock speed up not just multiplexer.

Comment: Did not understand your comment, This question is very hard to answer without knowing what your currently doing, If you could please show what you have tried, like `mul = a*b;` and how a,b, are driven and how mul is used.

Comment: I just mean that we just use like this a*b, then it just synthesis to design ware library. but my question is that what is the another way instead use design ware to speed up.

Comment: Also I understood your comment but I don't know another way. So I asked at stackoerflow. If I know some kind of the method I already told you but I don't know and I want to know really l.

Comment: I do not see how changing your algorithm causes a problem with the multiplier, if the inputs are driven cleanly, and the output is a flip-flop directly. In this scenario you would always have 1 full cycle for the multiplier to stabilise its output. Unless your changing wordlengths. From what I can tell there is currently no problem, because it meets timing.

Comment: @Morgan Sir As I know I need to change algorithm but this algorithm is very big.  So I just modified this algorithm to adjustable to time meeting almost. But this have still negative slack because the multiplier.

Comment: @Morgan , If I use design ware, should I have to constraint with multicycle ? For example, If I use 6 stage multiplier, then should I have to constraint to 6 multicycle ?

Comment: No DesignWare multi-cycle put the flip-flops into the middle of the multiplier logic, it will just take multiple cycles for the answer to come out. But every cycle you will get a new result.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all surrounding logic has been minimised, inputs from flip-flops output direct to flip-flops.

```
module multiplier(
  WDITH = 24
)(
  input                                clk,
  input        signed      [WIDTH-1:0] a,
  input        signed      [WIDTH-1:0] b,
  output logic signed [(WIDTH*2) -1:0] mul
);

logic          signed      [WIDTH-1:0] a_i;
logic          signed      [WIDTH-1:0] b_i;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  a_i <= a;
  b_i <= b;
  mul <= a_i * b_i;
end

endmodule
```

Having the `a*b` style in RTL allows the synthesis library to choose the best multiplier style (Area/power vs speed ). Assuming the question is a result of synthesis not being able to close timing.

What limits the multiplier speed?

Input width could be minimised to speed up design.

For ASIC design the next process node could be chosen ie going from 22nm to 14nm. For FPGA a more expensive chip supporting a faster multiplier speed.

Alternatively the target clock speed of the Multiplier could be halved and two used in parallel. Multi-cycle clocks could be used in synthesis if actual clock is to remain the same but the result sampled every other clock.

```
module multiplier(
  WDITH = 24
)(
  input                              clk,
  input                            rst_n,
  input        signed      [WIDTH-1:0] a,
  input        signed      [WIDTH-1:0] b,
  output logic signed [(WIDTH*2) -1:0] mul
);

logic          signed      [WIDTH-1:0] a1_i;
logic          signed      [WIDTH-1:0] b1_i;
logic          signed      [WIDTH-1:0] a2_i;
logic          signed      [WIDTH-1:0] b2_i;
logic          signed [(WIDTH*2) -1:0] mul1;
logic          signed [(WIDTH*2) -1:0] mul2;

logic state;
always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    state <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    state <= ~state;
  end
end

always @* begin
 mul1_i = a1_i * b1_i;
 mul2_i = a2_i * b2_i;
end

always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    a1_i <= 'b0;
    b1_i <= 'b0;
    a2_i <= 'b0;
    b2_i <= 'b0;
    mul  <= 'b0
  end
  else begin
    if (state) begin
      a1_i <= a;
      b1_i <= b;
      mul  <= mul2_i;
    end
    else begin
      a2_i <= a;
      b2_i <= b;
      mul  <= mul1_i;
    end 
  end
end

endmodule
```

Where `mul1_i` and  `mul2_i`; are given multi cycle properties in synthesis, so they have twice the clock period to resolve.

Another possibility is to instantiate a multi-cycle design ware multiplier, [using the designware Datapath and building block IP](http://www.synopsys.com/dw/buildingblock.php). They have 2,3,4,5 and 6 cycle multipliers.

An example of a [2-Stage Multiplier](http://www.synopsys.com/dw/ipdir.php?c=DW02_mult_2_stage) :

```
module DW02_mult_2_stage_inst( inst_A, inst_B, inst_TC, 
                               inst_CLK, PRODUCT_inst );

  parameter A_width = 8;
  parameter B_width = 8;

  input [A_width-1 : 0] inst_A;
  input [B_width-1 : 0] inst_B;
  input inst_TC;
  input inst_CLK;
  output [A_width+B_width-1 : 0] PRODUCT_inst;

  // Instance of DW02_mult_2_stage
  DW02_mult_2_stage #(A_width, B_width)
    U1 ( .A(inst_A),   .B(inst_B),   .TC(inst_TC), 
         .CLK(inst_CLK),   .PRODUCT(PRODUCT_inst) );

endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks, I think so. maybe I think there's 2 ways to improve things, As you said,  first to use modified multiplexer and use more high-tech. Unfortunately we can't choice the tech but we can make costume multiplexer.

Comment: If so, What kind custom multiplexer is existing?

Comment: @JamJI, I do not think any exist by default. You would have to build a small state machine to sequence it, and instantiate two multipliers.

Comment: Thanks, I think you talked about kind of booth algorithmic isn't it?

Comment: @JamJI, no, [booth algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm) is one of many types of multiplier that the synthesis tool might use, when you write `a*b`.  Assuming you do not have access to any type of multiplier that meets your timing requirments you have to take a higher level approack and start putting hardware in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that. 'you have to take a higher level approach and start putting hardware in parallel.' Especially, Do you have experience with regarding this? If so, would you please let me know sir?

Comment: Sir, your answer about I have to take higher level approach is some vague or roughly. This answer is some different as my expect in my question(how improve the multiplier without clock speed up).

Comment: @JamJI Sorry I do not understand, I have included an example of two multipliers in parallel. where they are give two clock cycles for the answer to resolve. This could be thought of as a 2 stage multiplier. it will synthesise to a larger area but meet timing easier. Your question is quite vague and I have tried to prompt you to edit it adding details. You can not magically make a multiplier faster with out changing some constraints, I do not know what constraints we can change in your case.

Comment: @JamJI could you edit the question to say why you want to speed up the multiplier, I have stated an assumption in my answer which is because it does not meet timing.